# Always get JsonReaderException while using Azure Push Notification in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to use azure push notification example ,like exactly in this example https://github.com/xamarin/customer-success-samples/tree/master/samples/Xamarin.Android/AzurePushNotification.Android

I did all steps,I can register device ,take an registration id with no problem  but I always get this JsonReaderException error when I try to send test push message from azure portal .Any help is appreciated,thanks.
default test message =

> {"data":{"message":"Notification Hub test notification"}}

And the error is

> "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from
>   JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: Integer. Path
>   ''"

And the GcmServiceBase (exactly like the sample )

```
namespace myapp.Droid
{
    [BroadcastReceiver(Permission = Constants.PERMISSION_GCM_INTENTS)]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { Constants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_MESSAGE },
            Categories = new string[] { "myapp.Droid" })]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { Constants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_REGISTRATION_CALLBACK },
            Categories = new string[] { "myapp.Droid" })]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { Constants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_LIBRARY_RETRY },
            Categories = new string[] { "myapp.Droid" })]
    public class GcmBroadcastReceiver : GcmBroadcastReceiverBase<GcmService>
    {
        public static string[] SENDER_IDS = { "my firebase sender id" };
        public const string HUB_NAME = "my hub namespace ";
        public const string HUB_LISTEN_SECRET = "SharedAccessKey in the azure";
    }

    [Service]
    public class GcmService : GcmServiceBase
    {
        private static NotificationHub hub;

        public GcmService() : base(GcmBroadcastReceiver.SENDER_IDS) { }

        public static void Initialize(Context context)
        {
            var cs = ConnectionString.CreateUsingSharedAccessKeyWithListenAccess(
      new Java.Net.URI ("sb://" + GcmBroadcastReceiver.HUB_NAME(actually I write my hub namespace in here bcz when I write hub name ,it gives NotificationHubResourceNotFoundException error,so I write Hub Namespace) + "-ns.servicebus.windows.net/"),
                GcmBroadcastReceiver.HUB_LISTEN_SECRET);

            hub = new NotificationHub(GcmBroadcastReceiver.HUB_NAME, cs, context);
        }

        public static void Register(Context Context)
        {
            GcmClient.Register(Context, GcmBroadcastReceiver.SENDER_IDS);
        }

        protected override void OnRegistered(Context context, string registrationId)
        {
            //Receive registration Id for sending GCM Push Notifications to
            if (hub != null)
            {
                var registration = hub.Register(registrationId, "TEST");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnUnRegistered(Context context, string registrationId)
        {
            if (hub != null)
            {
                hub.Unregister();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            // Push Notification arrived
            ShowLocalNotification(intent);

            // Do additiona messaging here...
        }

        private void ShowLocalNotification(Intent intent)
        {
            //Push Notification arrived
            if (intent != null || intent.Extras != null)
            {
                var msg = intent.Extras.GetString("message");

                msg = String.IsNullOrEmpty(msg) ? "No Message" : msg;

                // Instantiate the builder and set notification elements:
                Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .SetContentTitle("Push Notification Received")
                    .SetContentText(msg)
                    .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound);

                // Build the notification:
                Notification notification = builder.Build();

                // Get the notification manager:
                NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

                // Publish the notification:
                const int notificationId = 0;
                notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notification);
            }
        }

        protected override bool OnRecoverableError(Context context, string errorId)
        {
            //Some recoverable error happened
            return true;
        }

        protected override void OnError(Context context, string errorId)
        {
            //Some more serious error happened
        }
    }
}
```

And mainactivity is like this

```
[assembly: Permission(Name = "@PACKAGE_NAME@.permission.C2D_MESSAGE")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "@PACKAGE_NAME@.permission.C2D_MESSAGE")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.INTERNET")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK")]

namespace AzurePushNotification.Android
{
    [Activity (Label = "myapp.Android", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Initialize our Gcm Service Hub
            GcmService.Initialize (this);

            // Register for GCM
            GcmService.Register (this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide where exactly is this error happening? i.e. which line ? Did you debug it to see where exactly the code is breaking?

Comment: The error is happening in the OnMessage event ,its really weird,when I cancel the   ShowLocalNotification(intent); inside the OnMessage event ,still same error happening in the end of the onmessage event.

Comment: If you checked the message in the `OnMessage` event, what is the output of it? Maybe it's getting received in a wrong format which is actually weird as well?

Comment: when I check the code by step over (f10) ,its kinda working.It gets message from intent.Extras.GetString("message"); and other steps seems true kinda .But then stepping over onmessage event ,it gives this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the error,https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.AzurePushNotification/ this plugin causes the error .When I uninstall this,no more error.I guess this azurepush plugin must be used alone ,its kinda overriding some methods if you try to recieeve push messages by directly GCM.So only use this plugin alone.Dont keep it in project ,if you wont use this plugin.